# When does the adjoint operator map closed convex subsets to closed convex subset?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear continuous map between Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ and denote by $T':Y'\rightarrow X'$ the norm adjoint of $T$. Let $M\subseteq U'$ be a subset of
the unit sphere $U'$ of $Y'$. Let $C\subseteq M$ be any weak*-closed convex subset. Is the image $T'(C)$ weak*-closed in $X'$? Or more generally, assuming that $C$ is convex, under which additional conditions on $C$ is the image $T'(C)$ weak*-closed in $X'$?

Comment: I have forgotten to mention that we can also assume that $T'$ is injective on $M$!

Comment: Do you really mean the sphere, or do you mean the ball? Convex subsets of spheres might not be very big...

Comment: Yes, it I really mean the sphere. Think of $Y'$ as being an $L^1$-space...

Comment: Since weak-star closed subsets would be norm-closed, and since you have not put conditions on $T$, it seems a bit unlikely that you can find non-trivial conditions on $C$ alone that will guarantee what you're after.

Comment: For instance, take $X=Y=c_0$ and let $T$ be the operator which divides the $n$th co-ordinate by $n$.

Comment: This is very similar to a question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157069/linear-image-of-closed-convex-set

Comment: So you think that it is not true that $T'$ maps weak*-closed convex sets to weak*-closed convex set?

Comment: @Matthew Daws: Yes, it is the same question and since no one could really give a good answer there, I thought it would be better to put this question here...is there any problem with that?

Comment: @Peter: No; but if you look on this site, you'll see that it's generally considered good to cross-link.  You probably wouldn't know that as a new user, so I thought I'd highlight this for you.

Comment: Oh, ok. Now I know :)

Comment: Do we call you Peter or Andy? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157069/linear-image-of-closed-convex-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that $C$ is weak* closed I'm not sure whether you mean as a subset of $Y'$ or in the relative weak* topology on $M$. If the latter, the answer is obviously "no": take $T$ to be the identity map and let $C = M$ be a convex subset of the unit sphere which is not weak* closed. (Examples are easy to find, even in finite dimensions.) If the former, the answer is "yes", for then $C$ is a weak* closed subset of the closed unit ball, hence it is weak* compact, hence its image under a  weak* continuous map (which $T'$ is) must also be weak* compact, and hence weak* closed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it also would suffice to assume that $M$ itself is weak*-closed...?

Comment: Weak* compact (which is the same as weak* closed, if it's bounded).

Comment: So it is sufficient to assume that $C$ is weak*-closed and $M$ is weak*-closed. Is it also necessary to have that $C$ is weak*-closed?Can we give conditions on $C$, $M$ or $T'$ to have that for any $C\subseteq M$ the image $T'(C)$ is weak*-closed in $X'$?

Comment: Since the question is changing, maybe you'd better edit your original post to clarify what it is you really want.